# CSS in microsoft visual studio

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to get my page to display properly but am unable to do so.
When i inspect element i get 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { 
Which is referring to my first line of code
When i use it in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/grahamwalsh/6RnXM/ it works fine, but when i open it in microsoft visual studio the cards do not display

here is my css file

```
.profile {
width: 50px;
height: 80px;
color: black;
background-color: silver;
border: 1px solid black;
float: left;
line-height: 80px;
text-align: center;
margin: 2px;
}
.highlight {
background: yellow !important;
border:1px solid #000;
color: black;
}
```

Comment: Where exactly in Visual Studio do you expect to see the result? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Everything is fine in that CSS. The problem must be elsewhere; how are you embedding the CSS in your page?

Comment: You have a JavaScript error, so you need to show us code that (a) is JavaScript and (b) reproduces your error. Linking to a _working_ version doesn't let us identify the problem.

Comment: the file is called voting.css so i have it as <script src="Voting.css"></script> in the <head> of my html page

Comment: FYI, CSS doesn't throw syntax errors. It just fails to render...

Comment: That's not how to link to a style sheet. You want something more like `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="voting.css">`.

Comment: i changed it to the <link rel="styleSheet" type="text/css" href="voting.css"> and i still have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is making a folder for css file. for example, if the folder is called "css" then embedded like so:

```
<link href="/css/filename.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

always try to put it as on top as possible in the html file.